# Limits with L'Hopital - guessing and confirm: $\lim _{x \to 0^+} (1+x)^{\large\frac1{\sin x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

With L'Hopital I have$$\lim _{x \to 0^+} (1+x)^{\large\frac1{\sin x}}=\lim _{x \to 0_+} e^{\ln{(1+x)^\frac{1}{\sin x}}}=\lim _{x \to 0_+} e^{\ln(1+x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin x}$$
$$=\lim _{x \to 0_+} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{\sin x}=\lim _{x \to 0_+}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{\cos x}=1$$

I just want someone to confirm it is the limit and I want to ask too if there is any method that I can guess the limit without actually calculating it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Careful, you dropped the $e$ at the third equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one knows that
$$
\lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1, \quad \lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,
$$ then one may write, for $x \to 0^+$,
$$
(1+x)^{\large\frac{1}{\sin x}}=e^{\large \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\cdot \large \frac{x}{\sin x}}
$$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Here you went wrong

As you calculated $$\lim_{x \to 0}{{\ln(1+x)}*\frac{1}{\sin x}} \to 1$$$$\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac{{\ln(1+x)}}{x}*\frac{x}{\sin x}} \to e$$ and not $1$.

Another method is by noting these one-sided limits..

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x}{\sin x} =1$$

Comment: I was copying and pasting from above...